# Ошибка Heroku H10

Tags: python, развертывание, heroku

Всем привет, хочу задеплоить бота, но команда

```
heroku open
```

ничего не дает,
а в логах пишет это:

```
2018-11-25T08:07:26.614200+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):    
2018-11-25T08:07:26.614225+00:00 app[web.1]: File "amz_bot.py", line 1, in <module>    
2018-11-25T08:07:26.614351+00:00 app[web.1]: import telebot    
2018-11-25T08:07:26.614354+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'    
2018-11-25T08:07:26.692675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed    
2018-11-25T08:07:26.677035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1    
2018-11-25T08:13:42.310966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"  
   method=GET path="/" host=amz-telega-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=a20d440d-7588-4b3f-b2a9-30f7c107577d fwd="46.62.65.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https    
2018-11-25T08:15:22.086541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"  
   method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=amz-telega-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=c4e27822-8de7-44b9-a99b-644001d517f5 fwd="46.62.65.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https    
2018-11-25T08:18:18.130320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"  
   method=GET path="/" host=amz-telega-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=8960ecd8-442f-4432-ba2f-d43f2c1d25ac fwd="46.62.65.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-11-25T08:18:19.149663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
   method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=amz-telega-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=b281c032-95af-429b-8224-d299d1ff16e2 fwd="46.62.65.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   
2018-11-25T08:21:41.233595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"  
   method=GET path="/" host=amz-telega-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=d08e9a8b-868e-4974-bbfd- a09d02e73ab7 fwd="46.62.65.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https    
2018-11-25T08:21:43.267944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"  
   method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=amz-telega-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=ef9cf3d9-ba35- 42e4-a400-b2d996846a75 fwd="46.62.65.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=  protocol=https    
 !    Log stream timed out. Please try again.
```